# Header menu blocks datepicker display

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using Minton Template (http://coderthemes.com/minton_2.1/blue_hori/index.html)

[image]

As you can see from the image above, the top of datepicker being blocked by the fixed header menu. It seems the datepicker not automatically being placed at the bottom of the input field.

This is the JS code that I used.

```
jQuery('#date-range').datepicker({
    toggleActive: true
});
```

This happen on smaller screen. Bigger screen display correctly with the datepicker placed at the bottom of the input field as image below.[image: help i dont know how to resize this image]

I dont want the menu blocks the datepicker. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the z-index of datepicker.  the z-index in the css should be greater for the datepicker class than for the menubar.

check this [link for more information about z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: At first, I think it has nothing to do with z-index, since I already change it to 1000. But after a closer look, it turns out the z-index for the menu is 1030. So I change the date-picker's z-index accordingly and it works. Thanks.